# How to get context menu in IntelliJ with items such as "Update usages to reflect signature change" and "Bind constructor parameters to fields"?

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring, contextmenu

At [this point](https://youtu.be/bxy2JgqqKDU?t=2247) in a demo video on YouTube, a context menu is displayed. Items include:

- Update usages to reflect signature changes…
- Create filed for parameter 'statusRepository'
- Safe delete 'statusRepository'
- Bind constructor parameters to fields
- Put parameters on one line
- Generate overloaded constructor with default parameter values

Here is a screen shot.

[image]

➣ How do I display such a menu in IntelliJ 2021?

➣ Are these menu items available on the fixed pull-down menus or only on this context menu?

Comment: Intention Action? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html#apply-intention-actions.

Answer (score 0):

**Show Context Actions** in your IDE Keymap settings. See the [documentation for more details](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html#apply-intention-actions).

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on Windows/macOS

Comment: It's Alt+Enter on MacOS as well. Alt+Space is just for previewing the result that some actions in the Alt+Enter menu have AFAIK.